# Netbeans/PHP version increase on save

Tags: php, .htaccess, netbeans

So first off, this may be way too complicated, but I'll ask it in the hopes that there is a reasonably easy answer.

I have an `.htaccess` with the following:

```
#load php define file
php_value auto_prepend_file /home/p28004/domains/fvheeswijk.nl/public_html/warframe2/definer.php
```

---

```
<?php 
define("ROOT", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define("VERSION", "1.0.129");
?>
```

This ensures that every php script calls `definer.php`, which can define several variables. I am wanting to define a version number here.

One of the reasons I want a version number with small minors (like 1.0.129) is to be able to cache javascript files when needed, and reload them on update.

The version would in case denote:

- 1: The major update version
- 0: The minor update version
- 129: The number of saves happened since the start of 1.0, should be reset on any new major/minor version.

I want that on every **Save** of any file on the server, that some script increments the last version by 1, for example to 1.0.130. I foresee two possibilities already:

- Have some NetBeans plugin that does this for me.
- Do it in some other way by storing the `Last-modified` of all files that can be found on the server, and checking it after every upload/periodically.

Is this, *in any way*, feasible? Any general tips and/or explanation would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention it, but I am creating the PHP project from Remote Sources, so it automatically uploades the file already on save. I want to hook in after the save or upload somewhere, and there be able to change the version number.

Comment: what is your OS ? and how do you upload your file? ftp or sftp ?

Comment: @AlirezaFallah Running on Windows 8.1 (not sure why it would matter), and the upload is being done via netbeans directly

Comment: on your localhost ? I was thinking of do it by a shell script on linux

Comment: @AlirezaFallah I sadly do not have full server access to the webserver, just running on some cheap webhosting

Comment: unfortunately I dont know the answer, but I really interested in your question, this is a very nice problem :)

Comment: Does that cheap webhosting include a database? That seems like the most obvious way to handle it to my thinking. If it's not a DB-driven application, you could probably even just implement an SQLite DB to store/update the current revision. "definer.php" could read it, and "Save" can increment the revision, or reset it to zero in the case of a minor/major value change.

Comment: @GeminiDomino Yes, it does have a database, it's not that bad actually, just no full server access. However I am struggling on how to make the "Save" do anything in particular. (Using Netbeans)

Comment: I'm not very experienced with Netbeans, so I can't say, but if they can be used for basic database CRUD operations, my suggestion should be doable.

Comment: Generally stuff like this is done using some kind of continous integration (CI) system. Basically an external program/script that will monitor your source code directory (or more often a version control repository) and perform some actions when specific event happens (like saving/commiting files). These actions might consist of compiling source code, running unit tests, or incrementing version numbers. Not posting it as an answer, as it doesn't really apply to the workflow you have now.

Comment: @Mchl Thanks a lot for the comment, I'd appreciate it if you could post it as an answer with some additional advice as I think that a CI system is the best way to go now, with the results that googling gave me so far.